# Will .htaccess work with an ip only?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am testing a website on an ip. I don't have the domain name linked yet. I wanted to test the .htaccess and have it only show the name of the php file and not the full string. I am not displaying my real ip here.

Example I want this:

http://111.111.111.111/~myWebsite/?id=My-Linked-php-file.php

to display this:

http://111.111.111.111/~myWebsite/My-Linked-php-file

So when it's live it will look like:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/My-Linked-php-file**

But it's not working, so I am wondering if I need to use the domain name and not the ip. Is there a way around this?

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```bash
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/*$ ?id=$1 [L] # Should display only file name not /?id=
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/*$ ?id=$1&p=$2 [L] # Second var shows up as a folder.
```

Comment: If this is a bad question then please explain why and don't downvote without please. I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: No idea why it got downvoted, it is a valid question with attempted code ++

Comment: I did not downvote this but .htaccess does not depend on using a hostname, IP is fine.  Your rules are wrong, try an online rewrite rule validator/tester.  *Hint* - you've added an extra value to your path "~myWebsite" that you didn't account for in your rule.

Comment: Ah, that's it... the extra value is the actual cpanel. So I guess that has to be accounted for. Thanks so much!